# How Secure is using execFile for Bash Scripts?

Tags: bash, node.js, child-process

I have a node.js app which is using the child_process.execFile command to run a command-line utility.

I'm worried that it would be possible for a user to run commands locally (a `rm / -rf` horror scenario comes to mind).

How secure is using execFile for Bash scripts?  Any tips to ensure that flags I pass to execFile are escaped by the unix box hosting the server?

## Edit

To be more precise, I'm more wondering if the arguments being sent to the file could be interpreted as a command and executed.

The other concern is inside the bash script itself, which is technically outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Of course that is possible, control security with permissions. It is only as secure as you make it.

Comment: I'm just going to throw this in as a comment but I'd suggest never using user input for something like this. If there is a limited number of options, take the input and then select which flag to insert into the command, but don't directly put the users data into the command.

Comment: what do you mean by "flags I pass to execFile are escaped by the unix box hosting the server"?

Comment: The only arguments I am putting into the command are file names with full paths ( __dirname + '/' + filename ).  Filenames are set through a random UUID.  So technically no user input or data is being used in the command line.

Comment: The actual file that is being executed is statically set in code, I just did not know if the flags being pushed to the script were able to be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `child_process.execFile` by itself is perfectly safe as long as the user doesn't get to specify the command name.

It does not run the command in a shell (like `child_process.exec` does), so there is no need to escape anything.

Comment: Ahh, so the command being ran will interpret the arguments sent from the node server code as actual arguments.  Then really the security is up in the hands of the script itself and the commands it executes.

Comment: Right. The main thing to watch out for in the script itself is code injection in sed, awk or find, and to ensure that you handle (or ignore) arguments with spaces and line feeds.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was worried about.  I think the best way to take care of this (for me) would be to remove all spaces and new lines in the arguments being passed into the Bash script.  I can do this just before I add __dirname to the string, just to ensure if the absolute path has a space there will not be any issues.  Thanks again, wish I could upvote twice!

Answer (score 1):

`child_process.execFile` will execute commands with the user id of the node process, so it can do anything that user could do, which includes removing all the server files.

Not a good idea to let user pass in command as you seem to be implying by your question.

You could consider running the script in a sandbox by using `chroot`, and limiting the commands and what resides on the available file system, but this could get complet in a hurry.

The command you pass will get executed directly via some flavor of `exec`, so unless what you trying to execute is a script, it does not need to be escaped in any way.

Comment: I'm not allowing the user to set what file is being executed.  I'm more worried about the arguments being passed into the command could be interpreted as a command.

Comment: I wouldn't be so worried then.  Using absolute pathname for the command would also ensure you know what gets executed.

Comment: You don't have to escape anything if you're executing a script.