# NodeJS ExecFile Args Security

Tags: node.js, command, arguments, child-process

I've asked a similar question before, but I just really wanted to make sure this is true because it is a security issue. According to this question and the answer given...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15168405/4045156

...if you use execFile and allow **unsanitised** user-entered content to be inserted in the args, it is safe. Is that true? In my app the user cannot modify the name of the executable, only one of the args in the args array (they need to provide a fully custom piece of text which they type; there is no way for me to provide it as a list of options).

Note that I'm specifically using execFile. I don't know if the specific OS that is running the server matters (Windows vs Linux).

Example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
var execParams = ['--param-name', userSuppliedString]

exec('path-to-exe', execParams, {timeout: 120000}, function (err, data) {
});
```

Is this safe? Thanks for your help.

Comment: It depends upon the command line handling in the target executable and what it does with the user supplied string.  If it safely handles any possible string, then you're probably OK.  If it could get fooled into doing something unexpected by putting unexpected things in that string, then you could have some vulnerabilities.  AFAIK, the executable that gets run can't be influenced by that user supplied string so it's just what your executable does with that string.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you reference says you're safe because you aren't letting the user specify the file that gets executed.  I'm not sure where you see it says you are vulnerable when only passing args.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that it says you are vulnerable, I just wanted to confirm that it is not actually vulnerable. To make things clear maybe I should just say its the wkhtmltopdf library, which can take text for things like headers, etc. as parameters.

Comment: Only a thorough code review of that wkhtmltopdf library's source code could tell you whether it has vulnerabilities with the parameters you are passing it from the user.  If, for example, it could be passed an output file path/name, that could certainly create a vulnerability.  And, it could just have programming errors in option handling that create vulnerabilities.  Code review of the library's handling of everything you pass it from the user or strict sanitizing of the user options to set of known safe values would be needed.

Comment: I see. I may be best off just limiting the input to letters and numbers (and maybe spaces, periods and commas). It's hard to imagine someone doing something evil with just that. Thank you again.

Comment: Here's what I ended up with to remove everything except spaces, periods, commas, parenthesis, underscore, hyphen and exclamation points. It allows commonly used characters but removes what I believe are the more dangerous ones (forgive my less-than-efficient regex): text = text.replace(/[^\w\.\-\,\!\)\( ]/g, '');

Comment: Actually, I think it's wise to remove hyphens too. For anyone reading, please use at your own risk, but I think this is safe: text = text.replace(/[^\w\.\,\!\)\( ]/g, '');